# How to return pointer to struct from dictionary in MATLAB, instead of copy?

Tags: python, python-3.x, matlab, hashmap

I am translating some code from Python to MatLab, and I realized a difference in the way they store elements in a dictionary.  Comparing the two pieces of code, I’m hoping someone can confirm my perception:

In Matlab when a value in the dictionary is requested, a copy is returned, rather than a pointer.  So, if that value is modified, then the value in the dictionary remains unchanged.

In Python when a value in the dictionary is requested, a pointer to the object is returned. So, if that value is modified, then the value in the dictionary is changed as well.

In Matlab:

```
clear all; close all;  clc; 

some_dict_with_struct=containers.Map; 

some_dict_with_struct('a')=struct; 

item = some_dict_with_struct('a'); 

item.attribute = 1; 

disp(item.attribute); % displays "1" 

disp(some_dict_with_struct('a')); % has no fields?
```

In Python

```
class A: 

  def __init__(self,a): 

    self.a=a 

    return  

A(4) 

some_dict_with_struct={} 

item = A(4) 

some_dict_with_struct['a'] = item 

print(some_dict_with_struct['a'].a)  # returns "4" 

item.a = 0 

some_dict_with_struct['a'] 

print(some_dict_with_struct['a'].a) # returns "0"
```

Can someone please help me determine a comparable data structure to use in MatLab that will achieve similar behavior to that of Python?   And, could you please confirm that my perception of the behavior is correct?

Thanks.

Comment: "In Python when a value in the dictionary is requested, a pointer to the object is returned." no, it isn't. Python *doesn't have pointers*. Everything does essentially have reference semantics in Python, though. However, nothing is stopping you from implementing a container that *does* return a copy when you try to access an element, it's just that generally isn't the case (but again, you could create such a thing yourself).

Comment: Thanks, @juanpa.arrivillaga.  I understand that I used the word "pointer" probably incorrectly.  However, from your message it seems to me like you're suggesting to modify the Python code to return a copy.  Rather, what I'm trying to do is to modify the MatLab code to imitate Python.  Do you know of an easy way?  Or perhaps an easier data structure to use instead of `containers.Map`?  Thank you.

Comment: The only way you'll get object passed by reference in MATLAB is by using [Handle Classes](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/handle-classes.html). Either use a built-in handle class object, or create your custom one.

Comment: Thanks @Hoki!  I learned a lot from your comment.  Please read my answer below and let me know what you think!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is not with the `containers.Map`, but rather with the item it contains.  Instead of using a `struct`, the desired behavior can be captured in a handle class.

In a separate file called `Item.m`:

```
%% 

classdef Item < handle 

    properties 

        attribute = 0; 

    end 

end
```

Observe this behavior:

```
some_dict_with_struct=containers.Map; 

some_dict_with_struct('a') = Item; 

item = some_dict_with_struct('a'); 

item.attribute = 1; 

disp(item.attribute); % displays "1" 

disp(some_dict_with_struct('a')); % displays "1"
```

Comment: yep, that's probably the simplest way to get the behaviour you want. Your class `Item` can be built looking like a structure (or incorporating one) if you need. Just a minor nitpick: I know MATLAB is case sensitive, `item` and `Item` are treated differently, but for the sake of clarity in your example I would rename one of them so the difference is more obvious for someone reading your answer.